# how to update javascript function every minute and update chart?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to update my chart every minute and call the chart function. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help.

The page is here:-

http://www.api.jonathanlyon.com/m.html

Here is the code:-

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/oesmith/morris.js/0.3.2/morris.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Morris.js Line Chart Example</title>
</head>
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){

  chart()

}, 5000);
</script>

<script>
 morrisTemplate = {
      element: 'line-example',
      data: [
      ],
      xkey: 'x',
      xLabels: "hour",
      ykeys: ['volvo'],
      ymin: '0',
      labels: ['Volvo Fan Numbers']
    }


$(function chart(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.api.jonathanlyon.com/api_fanpage2.php?pagename=volvo&format=json&hourly=true",
        success: function (data){
            toPlot = []
            $.each(data[0]['pagename']['volvo']['data'], function(i, item){
                toPlot.push({x: item['date'] , volvo: item['newfans']   });
            });
            console.log("length:" + toPlot.length)
             toPlot.reverse()
            morrisTemplate.data = toPlot.slice(toPlot.length - 24, toPlot.length)
            Morris.Line(morrisTemplate);
         },
    });


})

</script>


<body>
  <div id="line-example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: Why is the chart function wrapped in a jquery selector?

Comment: @Roonaan, this is neat way in jQuery to say dom ready

Comment: not sure, should it not be?

Comment: how should I change it? Any help would be great

Comment: supposely this makes very first call for ajax on DOM ready, that's should be fine

Comment: You want to wrap your `setInterval`, not your `chart` function, in `$()` as that's the part that actually executes the code.

Comment: right, this is scope acces question

Comment: sorry I'm lost, can you explain more please @Mathletics

Comment: @JonathanLyon, what is Mathletics said, and what's is going on, when you run code in $() it makes separate execution scope, so function not accessible into global scope, consider example http://jsbin.com/ukoyot/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the outer `$()` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready()`. Go ahead and throw all your code into the jQuery wrapper to delay execution until the DOM is ready.

```
<script> 

$(function () {
    window.setInterval(chart, 5000);

    morrisTemplate = {
      element: 'line-example',
      data: [
      ],
      xkey: 'x',
      xLabels: "hour",
      ykeys: ['volvo'],
      ymin: '0',
      labels: ['Volvo Fan Numbers']
    }

    function chart(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.api.jonathanlyon.com/api_fanpage2.php?pagename=volvo&format=json&hourly=true",
            success: function (data){
                toPlot = []
                $.each(data[0]['pagename']['volvo']['data'], function(i, item){
                    toPlot.push({x: item['date'] , volvo: item['newfans']   });
                });
                console.log("length:" + toPlot.length)
                 toPlot.reverse()
                morrisTemplate.data = toPlot.slice(toPlot.length - 24, toPlot.length)
                Morris.Line(morrisTemplate);
             },
        });

    }
});

</script>
```

Also, you need to include your scripts in either the `head` or (better) the end of the `body` tag. Including elements outside of those elements is not valid markup.

Comment: thanks, it worked, kind of but was doing weird things, duplicating the chart, making it bigger etc etc, oh well, never mind, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

additionally you may split it like this

```
function chart(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.api.jonathanlyon.com/api_fanpage2.php?pagename=volvo&format=json&hourly=true",
            success: function (data){
            toPlot = []
            $.each(data[0]['pagename']['volvo']['data'], function(i, item){
                toPlot.push({x: item['date'] , volvo: item['newfans']   });
            });
            console.log("length:" + toPlot.length)
            toPlot.reverse()
            morrisTemplate.data = toPlot.slice(toPlot.length - 24, toPlot.length)
            Morris.Line(morrisTemplate);
        }
    });
}



$(function () {
    chart();
});
```

This is not most beautiful solution as it makes dirt in global scope, but quick

Comment: yes, because there is syntax error in function declaration, need to clean it up